# Override ActiveRecord find

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have done this in Rails 2.3.10 and 3.0.3 and it works

```
def self.find(*args)
  records = super  
  # Manipulate Records here.
end
```

I am looking for a base finder function in Rails 3 which I can replace for this functionality to be applied to Post.all, Post.first, Post.last etc.

Comment: It's almost never a good idea to modify core functionality like this. It's surprising in a bad way.

Can you give some context about what you're trying to achieve? There's probably a much cleaner and more maintainable solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My advice ... make a scope or a class method to do this instead:

e.g.

```
scope :my_scope, lambda {|...| ...}
```

then to apply

```
TheClass.my_scope.all
TheClass.my_scope.first
TheClass.my_scope.last
```

Answer (score 1):

`all`, `first`, and `last` are all just wrappers for `find` so redefining `find` should affect all of those. Take a look at how they're implemented in [ActiveRecord::FinderMethods](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods.html).

Comment: The find overwrite works just fine but for some reason it does not seem to work with all, first or last. I will give it another go.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are looking for this:

```
# File activerecord/lib/active_record/relation/finder_methods.rb, line 95
def find(*args)
  return to_a.find { |*block_args| yield(*block_args) } if block_given?

  options = args.extract_options!

  if options.present?
    apply_finder_options(options).find(*args)
  else
    case args.first
    when :first, :last, :all
      send(args.first)
    else
      find_with_ids(*args)
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

This will do what the original question was asking.

```
def self.find_by_sql(*args)
  records = super

  # Manipulate Records here

  return records
end
```